# Do something after every x time inside loop in php

Tags: php, loops

I want to do something after every specific iteration Something like

```
foreach($contents as $key => $content){
   if($key == 25) { do something.. }
   if($key == 50) { do something.. }
   if($key == 70) { do something.. }

}
```

I want to do something after every 25 iterations after like at 25 iterations then 50 and 75 then 100 and so on.
Note : i don't want to do this manually as data can be to big so i need smart solution.

Comment: `if ($key % 25 === 0)`

Comment: you can use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
  $i=0;   
  foreach($contents as $key => $content){
       $i++
       if($i == 25) {
          $i=0;

          do something..
       }

    }
```

Comment: suppose if there are 2000 iteration i can't use if condition for 25,50,60  to 2000

Comment: you told that you want to do something after every 25 iteration , So i provide this code. This code do something after every 25 iteration.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
$count = 24;
foreach($contents as $key => $content){

    if($key == $count) { 
        do something.. 
        $count = $count + 25;
    }

}
```

**OR:**

```
foreach($contents as $key => $content){

    if($key % 25 === 0) { 
        do something.. 
    }

}
```